# Best way to integrate frontend and backend without ajax or api

Tags: javascript, php, integration

I wanna use php variable in frontend framework like Vue js.

What is the best way of integration frontend and backend framework?

This is my idea, but i think there are better way to do this.

```
<script id = "data" >
    let $user = <?= json_encode($user) ?>
</script >
Some content... 

<script >
new Vue({
    data: {
        user: $user
    }, 

    mounted() {
        $("#data"). remove () 
    } 
})
```

Comment: Is there any reason for not using Ajax or an API?

Comment: @magnus yes! Simplicity

Comment: Using Ajax to fetch the data you need, when you need it is still far better than outputting all the data on the page just in case you need it. The browser can also cache the page better that way. Doing an Ajax request using jQuery (which you seem to be using anyway) is just a few more lines of code and isn't complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While 'simplicity' is wonderful, 'functionality' is also pretty critical...

Sometimes you can get by with your type of coding (use it for some things that come into the PHP file that are needed to load the page, for example), and what you have may work for this particular situation (and, no, there isn't any way I can see to make it "better"...), though most pages will need more data that is 'fluid', and you will quickly run out of projects where you can write only 'simple' code.

Learn to use ajax (it is pretty simple once you get the hang of it) and copy/paste from your own 'library' (save snippets in a place you remember - you will find MANY things you want to keep... - I keep a 'functions.php' file and over the years it has grown pretty large with great bits-n-pieces.)

Since you are using jQuery already, here's one way to do ajax... (there are others, again, study and find the way you like...)

```
var url = "https://theURLtoMyAjax.phpPage";
var elements = "theStuff=thatIwantToSend&someMore=somethingElse"; // this is like writing everything in the address bar - again, there are other ways...)
$.post(url, elements, function (data) {
        // do all kinds of wonderful things in here!
        // the 'data' is what is returned from your call, so you can use it to update data on the page, etc. 
    });
```

So, as you can see, only a couple lines of code to add Ajax and tons of things you can do once you do it, so learn it - and use it!

Happy coding!